# Aligning stackrel signs beneath each other using split

Tags: math-mode, equations, vertical-alignment

I'm typesetting a proof by induction using `split` to align equality signs precisely beneath each other. One of the signs should have 'IH' on top of it to indicate that the induction hypothesis has been used in that step. I'm using `stackrel` for that. However, since `\stackrel{IH}{=}` is wider than `=`, it doesn't align nicely. I tried two things with `split` (the `&` before or after the `=`sign) and also with `alignedat` (but that would only work if the center column would be center-aligned, which it's not, it's left-aligned. See the code example and its output:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
S_n &=                 2^iS_{n-i}+2^i-1\\
    &\stackrel{IH}{=}  2^i(2^1S_{n-i-1}+2^1-1)+2^i-1\\
    &=                 2^{i+1}S_{n-i-1}+2^{i+1}-1
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
S_n =&                2^iS_{n-i}+2^i-1\\
\stackrel{IH}{=}&     2^i(2^1S_{n-i-1}+2^1-1)+2^i-1\\
=&                    2^{i+1}S_{n-i-1}+2^{i+1}-1
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
S_n &=&&              2^iS_{n-i}+2^i-1\\
&\stackrel{IH}{=}&&   2^i(2^1S_{n-i-1}+2^1-1)+2^i-1\\
&=&&                  2^{i+1}S_{n-i-1}+2^{i+1}-1
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the equality signs and the equality signs with 'IH' above it are nowhere precisely beneath each other.

I don't *need* to use `split`, so solutions without `split` would be perfect as well. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `\mathmakebox` or `\mathclap` (thanks to Andrew) from `mathtools`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
S_n &=                 2^iS_{n-i}+2^i-1\\
    &\stackrel{\mathmakebox[\widthof{=}]{\mathrm{IH}}}{=}  2^i(2^1S_{n-i-1}+2^1-1)+2^i-1\\
    &=                 2^{i+1}S_{n-i-1}+2^{i+1}-1
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use `align*` also instead of `equation*` and `split`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
S_n &=                 2^iS_{n-i}+2^i-1\\
    &\stackrel{\mathclap{\mathrm{IH}}}{=}  2^i(2^1S_{n-i-1}+2^1-1)+2^i-1\\
    &=                 2^{i+1}S_{n-i-1}+2^{i+1}-1
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Please note that I have changed `IH` to `\mathrm{IH}`. (Thanks to egreg).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and the tip. I was already getting tired of writing `\begin{equation*}\begin{split}...\end{split}\end{equation*}` all the time.

Comment: If loading `mathtools` you could just use `\mathclap` on the symbol "IH" to hide is width.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Nice suggestion, I have added it to the answer.thank you.

Comment: `IH` with math letters is really bad. Use either `\mathrm{IH}` or `\mathit{IH}`

Comment: @egreg I have no idea to be honest. What may be IH?

Comment: “Induction hypothesis”

Answer (score 12):

In fact, the solutions above are not optimal because the example given is a very special case: `IH` has almost the same width as `=`, so there is no problem on the right side. But consider what happens when we need something significantly larger than `IH`, like in

```
\begin{align*}
S_n &= 2^iS_{n-1}+2^i-1\\
&\stackrel{\mathrm{IH,IG,IK,IL}}{=}2^i(2^1S_{n-i-1}+2^1-1)+2^i-1\\
&= 2^{i+1}S_{n-i-1}+2^{i+1}-1
\end{align*}
```

Then the right part of `IH,IG,IK,IL` will overlap on the formula!

My solution is to define `\leftstackrel`, which aligns perfectly on the left but adds the necessary white space on the right so that there is no overlap. Here is the code:

```
\newlength{\leftstackrelawd}
\newlength{\leftstackrelbwd}
\def\leftstackrel#1#2{\settowidth{\leftstackrelawd}%
{${{}^{#1}}$}\settowidth{\leftstackrelbwd}{$#2$}%
\addtolength{\leftstackrelawd}{-\leftstackrelbwd}%
\leavevmode\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\leftstackrelawd>0pt}}%
{\kern-.5\leftstackrelawd}{}\mathrel{\mathop{#2}\limits^{#1}}}
```

and it can be used simply as:

```
\begin{align*}
S_n &= 2^iS_{n-1}+2^i-1\\
&\leftstackrel{\mathrm{IH,IG,IK,IL}}{=}2^i(2^1S_{n-i-1}+2^1-1)+2^i-1\\
&= 2^{i+1}S_{n-i-1}+2^{i+1}-1
\end{align*}
```

Compare (1.1) (legacy `\stackrel`), (1.2) (`\stackrel` proposed above) and (1.3) (`\leftstackrel`) in the figure below

[image: figure]
<sub>(source: [fluxus-virus.com](http://www.fluxus-virus.com/fichiers/2015-09-04_14-58-05.png))</sub>

Comment: The \leftstackrelawd>0pt part produces errors in overleaf.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest three strategies. The first one is to define a command `\iheq` that prints an equals sign with some padding to become the same width as `\overset{\mathrm{IH}}{=}`, which can be simply obtained with `\iheq*`.

The second strategy is adding “(IH)” to the side.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\iheq}{s}{%
  \overset{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\mathrm{IH}}{\hphantom{\mathrm{IH}}}}{=}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
S_n &\iheq  2^iS_{n-i}+2^i-1\\
    &\iheq* 2^i(2^1S_{n-i-1}+2^1-1)+2^i-1\\
    &\iheq  2^{i+1}S_{n-i-1}+2^{i+1}-1
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
S_n &= 2^iS_{n-i}+2^i-1\\
    &= 2^i(2^1S_{n-i-1}+2^1-1)+2^i-1 && \makebox[0pt][l]{(IH)}\\
    &= 2^{i+1}S_{n-i-1}+2^{i+1}-1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Third strategy: make IH smaller and ensure it's zero width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\iheq}{s}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\overset{\IH}{=}}{=}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\IH}{}{%
  \hidewidth\scriptscriptstyle\mathrm{IH}\hidewidth
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
S_n &\iheq  2^iS_{n-i}+2^i-1\\
    &\iheq* 2^i(2^1S_{n-i-1}+2^1-1)+2^i-1\\
    &\iheq  2^{i+1}S_{n-i-1}+2^{i+1}-1
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a problem which is annoying me every time, let me put my two cents in.

A solution which may not be that elegant, but that I like for its outcome, is to use a `\phantom` command to make all the other `=` signs as large and as high as the incriminated one, as in the following

```
\begin{align*}
S_n & \stackrel{\phantom{\mathrm{IH}}}{=} 2^iS_{n-i}+2^i-1 \\
    & \stackrel{\mathrm{IH}}{=}           2^i(2^1S_{n-i-1}+2^1-1)+2^i-1\\
    & \stackrel{\phantom{\mathrm{IH}}}{=} 2^{i+1}S_{n-i-1}+2^{i+1}-1
\end{align*}
```

This is the outcome
[image: alignwithphantom]
and it works also for longer labels, provided that you appreciate a large space around the `=` sign.

Notice that, in addition, it may be combined with the `\mathmakebox` command from `mathtools` in order to deal with multiple labels of different length, as in the following pathological example:

```
\begin{align*}
S_n & \stackrel{\phantom{\mathrm{IH,(3.14)}}}{=}
      2^iS_{n-i}+2^i-1 \\
    & \stackrel{\mathrm{IH}}{\mathmakebox[\widthof{$\stackrel{\mathrm{IH,(3.14)}}{=}$}]{=}}
      2^i(2^1S_{n-i-1}+2^1-1)+2^i-1\\
    & \stackrel{\mathrm{IH,(3.14)}}{=}
      2^{i+1}S_{n-i-1}+2^{i+1}-1
\end{align*}
```

whose outcome is
[image: alignwithphantomandmathmakebox]